# I want to control a python script over PHP/HTML

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Ok, I googled for few hours and still didn't find any solutions.

I want to control a python script over **php/html**.

I have two files:

**proba.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
  <head>
     <title>Start</title>
  </head>
  <form method="post">
     <input type="submit" value="GO" name="GO">
  </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['GO']))
  {
      shell_exec("python relay1on.py");
      echo "success";
  }
   ?>
```

**relay1on.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPio.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7,True)
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

If I try to run that HTML file and press button Go, nothing happens.

I tried chmod +x xxx.py script, and tried sudo visudo www- ....

I'm losing my mind over this, so help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: In the code you posted here, the curly bracket doesn't close; maybe that's the problem? Also maybe put a `print` in the python script as well, to see if it's executed at all

Comment: // , Please post your research. What did you Google? Also, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving the posted request properly? You'll need to watch both client logs (Network tab) and the server logs.

Comment: I'm sure my problem is in premissions. I watched youtube videos for simple switch relays, also I used github code for this kind of stuff, but It just doesn't want to trigger. Python code for triggering GPIO relay1on.py is 100% correct, so only problem is with html/php file.

I looked for all sorts of codes out there for simple relay on-off button but nothing works.
btw apache and php installed, also I'm using raspberry 3b+

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a web server too? Fairly sure if you're just running this as a single HTML file nothing will happen because by pushing the "GO" button, nothing is actually happening in the back end, you're just seeing the button but nothing is being passed to a web server for further action. Using apache might be a good place to start to get your web page displayed with a web server?

Comment: I'm running apache server on raspberry. I can access raspberry over ip from local network, but wont triger any scripts. If I connect with ssh and manualy write smth like sudo python xxx.py it will triger script without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was "sudo visudo" premissions. Thanks for help. Cheers!